# Recordset: blank for string records?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 excel workbooks and I am pulling data (A1:A20)from one (WB1) to another using below macro. I have problem that only records with numbers are pulled while string records are not. It seems that the field type is considered as a number and only numbers are being pulled. what should I change in the code to solve it?

below link includes the source file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B64seB8-qtdLYk80N3hvX2F6VGc

```
Private Source As Variant

Sub Copy_Paste()
'copy the data from the source
Source = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\WB1.xlsx"
GetData Source, "Sheet1", "A1:A20", Sheets("Database").Range("A1")
End Sub

Public Sub GetData(Source As Variant, SourceSheet As String, SourceRange As String, TargetRange As Range)
Dim rsCon As Object
Dim rsData As Object
Dim szSQL As String
Dim szConnect As String
'Create the connection string based on excel version
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & Source & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No"";"
    Else
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & Source & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No"";"
    End If
szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & SourceRange$ & "];"

On Error GoTo SomethingWrong
Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsCon.Open szConnect
rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, 0, 1, 1
' Check to make sure we received data and copy the data
If Not rsData.EOF Then
    TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
Else
    MsgBox "No records returned from : " & Source, vbCritical
End If
' Clean up our Recordset object.
rsData.Close
Set rsData = Nothing
rsCon.Close
Set rsCon = Nothing
Exit Sub
SomethingWrong:
    MsgBox "The file name, Sheet name is invalid of : " & Source, vbExclamation, "Error"
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

See here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ce095b10-84a4-4ae3-8944-70a2b53daa44/mixed-data-types-in-excel-column-to-oedb-destination?forum=sqlintegrationservices

You need to add IMEX=1 to your connection strings.  Eg:

```
szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & Source & ";" & _
                "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1"";"
```

Otherwise, the driver guesses your data column is numeric (based on the first few rows) and ignores any non-numeric values.